# How to characterize elements in the Bruhat open cell?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

This might be an elementary question. For simplicity, let's assume $G=GL(n,F)$, where $F$ is a local field. Let $U$ be the subgroup of upper triangular unipotents, $A$ the subgroup of diagonal matrices. $\omega_n$ the longest Weyl element. Then $\Omega=U\omega_nAU$ is the open Bruhat cell.

Now I want to ask how to determine if a given matrix $g=(g_{ij})\in \Omega$?

For example, an easy calculation shows that if $g=(g_{ij})\in \Omega$, then $g_{n1}\ne 0$. But I'm not sure if this is also sufficient.

Of course, other characterizations are also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of the open Bruhat cell are precisely the matrices where the determinant of the $k\times k$ minor of the bottom left hand corner of the matrix is non-zero for all $k\leq n$.  You noted one of these conditions for $k=1$.  This condition is true for $\omega_nA$, and won't be changed by multiplication by upper triangular matrices.  You can check this is sufficient by solving for the upper triangular matrices.